# Managing architecture release for react-native android

Tags: android, google-play, react-native

Google set an deadline for updating the apk files for apps so they need to have separate files for all architectures versions.

So in the build.gradle file I have made the following changes:

```
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = true
...
splits {
        abi {
            ...
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86-64"
            ...
        }
    }
...
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->

            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2, "arm64-v8a":3, "x86-64":4]
            ...
        }
    }
```

At first I thought that it worked fine since in the ...android\app\build\outputs\apk\release directory I have found few files instead of one. However first thing that surprised me was the fact that I received 3 files versions : arm64-v8a, x86 and armeabi-v7a. 
Is this correct that x86-64 version was not generated?

The second thing is that when I updated the files on google play console, I am still getting the message that the files are not separated accordingly by the architecture version. Is there anything more that I should have done?

Comment: I think you're confused.  Google set a date where all apps must support 64 bit-  not when all apps must have a separate 64 bit APK.  Supporting via a multi-ABI apk bundle is still allowed.  This all starts as of Aug 1 2019 (with a few exceptions).

Comment: I received email with this msg: "By August 1, 2019, all apps that use native code must provide a 64-bit version in addition to the 32-bit version in order to publish an update. This past January, we reiterated that this is required in order to make way for innovation and in anticipation of future Android devices that only support 64-bit code." 

I understood it that I should provide a separate 64bit version, but I am not 100% sure about this

Comment: This means that all apps must support 64 bit CPUs.  It doesn't mean they need separate app bundles.  Although it won't hurt to do that, you'll have smaller downloads from the play store.  SO its not a waste, although I highly recommend you automate your build uploads with Fastlane or the like if doing this.

Comment: As for x86-64 binaries-  are you sure all your libraries provide them?  THis is the one that would concern me the least, as the only major use of x86-64 on Android devices is for emulators-  99%+ of all phones/tablets are ARM.

Comment: I was trying to split the apk file earlier but, got some issues and just put it on my todo list ;) But since the google reminded me about it I assumed that it should be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found it. Should use "x86_64" instead of "x86-64". Then it generates all 4 versions.